# What exactly is Autoboxing in Java

Tags: java

```
class BoxingExample1{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    int a=50;  
        Integer a2=new Integer(a);//Boxing  

        Integer a3=5;//Boxing  

        System.out.println(a2+" "+a3);  
 }   
}
```

**So in this example is the class Integer being created or what???**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Integer a2=new Integer(a);//Boxing
```

That is not autoboxing. You are just building an Integer object using [Integer's constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(int)) with value 5.

Where the second statement

```
Integer a3=5;//Boxing
```

Is Actual autoboxing is *[the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)*